# active_admin, nested routes and custom view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, nested-resources

i just start playing with active_admin, I have 2 resources:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :name, :presence => true
  has_many :auctions  
end
```

and

```
class Auction < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
end
```

under app/admin I have auctions.rb and categories.rb

```
ActiveAdmin.register Auction do
end
ActiveAdmin.register Category do
end
```

my questions are:

- in order to show all the auctions for a given category what should i do to generate the nested resource for it? (/admin/categories/1/auctions)
- in my frontend i have to show all the auctions without the admin/ prefix, basically I need this http://local/auctions available, I tried to add in the routes.rb the directive resources :auctions but I need to generare a new auctions controller outside the admin/ scope. Is this a good way to take?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

First, what you could do, is to place this activeadmin directive in the 'register' block

```
ActiveAdmin.register Auction do
  belongs_to :auction
end
```

You may want to check out this page: https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/issues/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=belongs_to

And second; that is indeed the right way. Create a separate auctions controller outside the admin scope. Good luck.